# Are any high-profile websites using a .NET ecommerce/shopping cart solution?

Tags: .net, asp.net

nopCommerce seems the popular option, but their showcase doesn't exactly contain high-profile websites.

Are any using a .NET ecommerce solution? It could be a name brand or a high-transactional site.

Comment: You might take a look at this list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750022/high-profile-asp-net-websites

Comment: High profile almost always means custom built software so not exactly the fairest comparison. NewEgg is a great example of a very high profile site built on asp.net. Zecco also uses it atleast partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of sites wont publish this because if a security hole is found - then they can be easily targeted. 
However - aspdotnet store front has some high profile customers:

http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/t-portfolio.aspx